# best practices for integrating with VSO

Tags: wcf, azure-devops, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have to implement a number of integrations with VSO from different applications using BizTalk Server 2013 R2.
Can someone help me decide which will be the best approach among the below three options:

1. WCF Service:
   We can create a WCF service which will have reference of library provided by VSO and have common methods to interact with VSO. We will use extensible client library for dot net provided by VSO.
2. Utility Class:
   This class will have same methods as in WCF service above, but I guess this will be faster as it will be added inside the BizTalk Solution and will be called from orchestration.
3. Common BizTalk Orchestration using Web-Http Adapter for calling REST APIs provided by VSO.

Please help me decide among these approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your scenario and the need of reuse of VSO functionality within BizTalk or outside BizTalk.

If BizTalk if the only consumer of VSO functionality, then you can directly use .NET library provided by VSO. From design perspective, its a good practice to wrap a third party library within your own .net library with your specific functionality, which will allow you to reuse the functionality across different applications if required.

WCF Service you would only want in case you want to expose this functionality outside BizTalk environment or if you have multiple BizTalk environment in which you want to share the same implementation.